# В коде не работает тэг :nth-child

Tags: html, css

```css
.social {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 31px;
  height: 31px;
  background: black;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 31px;
  margin-right: 11px;
}

.social div:nth-child(3) {
  margin-right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="social-block clearfix">
  <a class="social" href="#">
    <img src="img/yt.png">
  </a>
  <a class="social" href="#">
    <img src="img/fb.png">
  </a>
  <a class="social" href="#">
    <img src="img/vk.png">
  </a>
</div>
```

Нужно применить margin-right ко всем элемента кроме последнего.

Comment: не правильно селекторы прописаны... от родителя к дочернему... и вот так `div .social:nth-child(3)`

Answer (score 0):

Итак, в твоем коде обнаружено сразу 2 проблемы.

1- `nth-child` в твоем случае необходимо применять к `.social-block`, так как он родитель, или непосредственно к .

2-`nth-child` работает для конкретного елемента (html тега), ты указываеш `div`, а нужно применить его к `a`.

Вот рабочий CSS:

```
.social-block a:nth-child(3) {
  margin-right: 0px;
}
```

Пытался пояснить максимально просто, надеюсь у меня вышло. Удачи тебе :)

Comment: Вы тут что-то пропустили: `непосредственно к .` и у второго "к" тоже.

Comment: Хотел оформить тег как <div>, а оно почему-то не отображает текст в <>. Уже поправил.